# why main.jpg not showing

Tags: html, css

why main.jpg not showing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <title>W3.CSS Template</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta name="description" content="middleEastern furniture" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" />

  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: white;
      }
    </style>
  </head>

 

    <!-- Header -->
    <header>
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <br />
      <div
        style="
          background-image: url('pictures\main.JPG');
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center;
        "
      ></div>
    </header>
```

i was expecting the picture to show. it did not and it is not the pathway is wrong or the file name is wrong

Comment: main.jpg or main.JPG. Many systems are case-sensitive.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, the pathway is wrong since you used a backslash "\" instead of a regular slash "/". It should be:

```
background-image: url('pictures/main.JPG');
```

Second of all, your div element has no size or anything so the image won't show.
For example:

```
<div
    style="
      background-image: url('pictures/main.JPG');
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: center;"
  >Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
```

In the background of the text, it should show the image.